# Docker - php-apache & MongoDB connection issue

Tags: mongodb, docker, laravel-5

I'm running an Apache-PHP container
and I also run a MongoDB container. Both containers are run fine.
But when I connect MongoDB container from Apache-PHP container, there is an error.
[image]

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  admin-server:
    build:
      context: ./php-apache
    dockerfile: Dockerfile  
    container_name: admin-server
    ports: 
      - 8080:80
    volumes: 
      - ./www/app1:/var/www/html
      - ./php-apache/apache.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    links: 
      - mongo-database
    networks:
      - development_network

  mongo-database:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: monog-database
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - development_network
networks:
  development_network:
```

I'm running a laravel appliation and here is my mongodb connection:

```
'mongodb' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 27017,
        'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('MONGO_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'options' => [
            'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE') // sets the authentication database required by mongo 3
        ]
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `docker-compose.yaml` file you can access you `mongodb` container on `127.0.0.1:27017` only from host machine.

Containers communicate with each other in `development_network` network, so you can access your `mongodb` container on `mongo-database:27017` from `admin-server` container.

Just change laravel application's configuration:

```
'mongodb' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'host' => 'mongo-database',
        'port' => 27017,
        'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('MONGO_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'options' => [
            'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE') // sets the authentication database required by mongo 3
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Nickolay, it's fully working now.